# cURL code to unfollow instagram unfollowers

Tags: php, curl, instagram

```
<?php

Class Instagram
{
public $username;
public $password;
private $guid;
private $my_uid;
private $userAgent = 'Instagram 6.21.2 Android (19/4.4.2; 480dpi; 1152x1920; Meizu; MX4; mx4; mt6595; en_US)';
private $instaSignature ='25eace5393646842f0d0c3fb2ac7d3cfa15c052436ee86b5406a8433f54d24a5';
private $instagramUrl = 'https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/';



public function Login($username, $password) {
    $this->username = $username;
    $this->password = $password;    
    $this->guid = $this->GenerateGuid();
    $device_id = "android-" . $this->guid;  
    $data = '{"device_id":"'.$device_id.'","guid":"'.$this->guid.'","username":"'. $this->username.'","password":"'.$this->password.'","Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"}';
    $sig = $this->GenerateSignature($data);
    $data = 'signed_body='.$sig.'.'.urlencode($data).'&ig_sig_key_version=6';   
    $myid = $this->Request('accounts/login/', true, $data, false);  
    $decode = json_decode($myid[1], true); 
    $this->my_uid = $decode['logged_in_user']['pk'];
    print_r($this->my_uid); 
    return $myid;
}


public function PostFollow($user_id) {
    $device_id = "android-".$this->guid;
    $data = '{"device_id":"'.$device_id.'","guid":"'. $this->guid .'","uid":"'.$this->my_uid.'","module_name":"feed_timeline","user_id":"'.$user_id.'","source_type":"5","filter_type":"0","extra":"{}","Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"}';   
    $sig = $this->GenerateSignature($data);
    $new_data = 'signed_body='.$sig.'.'.urlencode($data).'&ig_sig_key_version=6';
    return $this->Request('friendships/create/'.$user_id.'/', true, $new_data, true);   
}

public function PostUnFollow($user_id) {
    $device_id = "android-".$this->guid;
    $data = '{"device_id":"'.$device_id.'","guid":"'. $this->guid .'","uid":"'.$this->my_uid.'","module_name":"feed_timeline","user_id":"'.$user_id.'","source_type":"5","filter_type":"0","extra":"{}","Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"}';   
    $sig = $this->GenerateSignature($data);
    $new_data = 'signed_body='.$sig.'.'.urlencode($data).'&ig_sig_key_version=6';
    return $this->Request('friendships/create/'.$user_id.'/', false, $new_data, true);  
} 





}
?>
```

`return $this->Request('friendships/create/'.$user_id.'/', false, $new_data, true)` - is this a correct cURL request?

Please refer to postfollow function (my follow code).

I want that the postUnfollow function will trigger auto unfollow users.

Comment: what do you mean _is this a correct cURL request?_ haven't you tried to check what `->Request()` method does? if its an external library, just investigate it

Comment: I've updated my question... can you review it sir? and give me some advice?

Comment: I'm developing an IG profile management app that you can follow/unfollow users

Answer (score 3):

Please check my below code and check it's work or not

```
public function PostUnFollow($user_id,$username) {
    $device_id = "android-".$this->guid;
    $data = '{"device_id":"'.$device_id.'","guid":"'. $this->guid .'","uid":"'.$this->my_uid.'","module_name":"feed_timeline","user_id":"'.$user_id.'","source_type":"5","filter_type":"0","extra":"{}","Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"}';   
    $sig = $this->GenerateSignature($data);
    $new_data = 'signed_body='.$sig.'.'.urlencode($data).'&ig_sig_key_version=6';
    return $this->Request('friendships/destroy/'.$user_id.'/', true, $new_data, true,$username);  

}
```